# how to query between multi tables in django

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

See some snippets please:

1.Model UserProfile:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    HEAD_CHOICE = (
        ('1', 'M'),
        ('2', 'F'),
    )
    image_id = models.CharField(max_length=2,  choices=HEAD_CHOICE, default='2')
```

2.Model TimeLine:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserProfile

class TimeLine(models.Model):
     user  = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
```

3.TimeLine's views.py

```
from models import TimeLine
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def index(request):
   timelinedict = TimeLine.objects.all()
   return render_to_response('timeline.html', locals())
```

**Question**: how can I make the var `'timelinedict'` contain fields (`image_id`, `email`) of UserProfile.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Just a suggestion (not related to your question): If you want to access foreign key table elements from the parent table queryset then fetch the parent table using [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). This will save some database hits for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: how can I make the var 'timelinedict' contain fields
>   (`image_id`, `email`) of `UserProfile`.

It already does:

```
from models import TimeLine
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
   timelinedict = TimeLine.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'timeline.html', {'objects': timelinedict})
```

In `timeline.html`:

```
{% for obj in objects %}
   {{ obj.user.email }}
   {{ obj.user.image_id }}
{% endfor %}
```

1. Use the `render` shortcut, not `render_to_response`. `render` will return the correct *request context*, which is useful when you are processing forms. It is best to get into the habit of using `render`.
2. Don't use `locals()`; because you will send *every variable* in the scope to your template. This is never what you want. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: works! well, could you tell why not use render_to_response and why not use locals()

Comment: render is good, but if I know what I will send by locals(),  I can use it, cause it makes my finger feel better. thx

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything special, you can directly access those attributes from instance of `TimeLine`.

For example

```
for t in TimeLine.objects.all():
    print t.user.image_id, t.user.email
```

Similarly you can use that in template as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your example for `timelinedict` isn't actually a `dict` it's a `queryset` containing TimeLine objects.

I think using the `@property` decorator as below will allow you to attach attributes to your TimeLine model objects.

```
class TimeLine(models.Model):
    user  = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)

    @property
    def image_id(self):
        return self.user.image_id

    @property
    def email(self):
        return self.user.email
```

Of course, you could just access them directly in your template via object.user.image_id, etc.